# Opposite of required_if in laravel using multiple value evaluation

Tags: laravel

How to validate *must null* if another field has specific value or *not null*

In my case it is the opposite of `required_if` with multiple values

```php
$rule = array(
  'selection' => 'required',
  'stext' => 'required_if:selection,2|required_if:selection,3',// stext should be null if selection is 2 or 3 
);
```

And if needed how to perform own validation?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your title? It's not really clear what you want

Comment: You need a custom validation rule for doing that, check this:https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to extend the validation rule. put the following in **AppServiceProvider**:

```php
Validator::extend('null_if', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $other = $parameters[0];
    $other_value = array_get(request()->toArray(), $other);
    if ($parameters[1] == $other_value) {
        return empty($value);
    }
    return true;
});
```

Tell me if it's work or what error given to you.

Comment: where i place "selection" field name

Comment: use it same as required_if just put null_if instead

Comment: 'stext' => 'null_if:selection,2|null_if:selection,3'

Comment: Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\Form001Controller::$attributes

Comment: my mistake. I modified my answer. try again. also, what's your Laravel version? notes array helper does not work in L5.8

Comment: glad to hear that

Answer (score 1):

So in your example you can do something like this:

```
$rule = array(
  'selection' => 'required',
  'stext' => 'required'
);

// override the rule
if(in_array(request('selection'), [2, 3])) 
{
  $rule['stext'] = 'nullable';
}
```

This means if the selection is 2 the field will be required and if the `selection` field has any other value the `stext` field will be required.

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. In any case the opposite of `required_if` is `required_without` so you can use that one if you want this field to be required even if the selection is empty.

With custom rule your passes method should look like this:

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class CustomRule implements Rule
{

    protected $selection;

    public __construct($selection)
    {
        $this->selection = $selection;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return $value === null && in_array($this->selection, [2, 3]);
    }
}
```

You use it like this:

```
$rule['stext'] = [ new CustomRule(request('selection') ]
```

Comment: I think he means that if selection is 2 or 3 stext has to be null

Comment: in my case I need "must_null_if" that is opposite of "required_if"

Comment: check my edit now then. That's why I said `required_without` is the opposite.

Comment: my stext field must null if selection is 2 or 3

Comment: I think I got you now. You can either do it with a custom rule, or you use my edit.